# Bash script to mass rename mp3s?

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a music library of mp3s (with correct metadata) organized like so: `Music/{artists}/{album}/{title}`

For example: `Music/Green Day/American Idiot/<songs in the album>`

Each mp3 is named like so:
`{title} {artists} {album}.mp3`

For example:
`Jesus of Suburbia Green Day American Idiot.mp3`

Keeping the same directory structure, I would like to rename each file so that it is titled like so: `{title} - {artists} - {album}.mp3`

For example `Jesus of Suburbia Green Day American Idiot.mp3` --> `Jesus of Suburbia - Green Day - American Idiot.mp3`

I was hoping someone would know of a script that could do this?

Thanks for the help.

P.S.

Songs that have multiple artists are organized somewhat differently

For example, in the music library we have both

`Music/Fall Out Boy/Save Rock And Roll/<most of the songs in the album>`

and

`Music/Fall Out Boy,Elton John/Save Rock And Roll/Save Rock And Roll Fall Out Boy,Elton John Save Rock And Roll.mp3`

This one isn't the best example, as it may be confusing because that song shares the same name as the album, which is why it appears twice in the mp3's name.

EDIT:
Based on your search suggestions, I was able to find a command:

`ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=title,artist,album -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 file.mp3`

Which can extract the metadata attributes that I need. I'm not sure how to apply this to be able to rename files though...

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far?  you mention the metadata is correct sooo ... have you figured out how to (programmatically) obtain the metadata for a given mp3 file? (and if not, have you tried a google search on `bash extract metadata from mp3 files` for ideas on how to obtain the metadata?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your research, you can get title/artist/album from mp3 file by executing: `ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=title -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 mymp3.mp3`

So we just need to make a function to build mp3 name by concatenating those strings:

```
function mp3name() {
  local title="$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=title -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1")"
  local artist="$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=artist -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1")"
  local album="$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=album -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1")"
  mkdir -p "$artist/$album"
  local name="$artist/$album/$title - $artist - $album.mp3"
  echo "$name"
  mv "$1" "$name"
}
```

Then we can use `find` and it's `exec` argument to execute above function on mp3's

```
export -f mp3name
find -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'mp3name "$@"' bash {} \;
```

Example mp3 file can be taken from: https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-mp3-download/

Result:

```
$ ls
'Impact Moderato - Kevin MacLeod - YouTube Audio Library.mp3'
```

Comment: This works great when the mp3s current names are one word, but if the directory that they're in or the file name has spaces, I get errors like so: https://imgur.com/a/7g5CHBs

Comment: @Jasper1378 that's because I forgot to put quote enclosing `$1`, now its fixed to `"$1"`, see my edit

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I discovered one more issue. Like I mentioned in the original post, my music is organized in sub-directories by artist and album. When I run the script, the renamed mp3s are all in a single top-level directory...

Comment: I think it might be because the files are being renamed from ```/artist/album/song.mp3``` to ```song.mp3```

Comment: @Jasper1378 okay, edited my answer, you can use `mkdir-p` to create the parent directory if they doesn't exist already

Comment: Just putting this here for future viewers: I added the lines ```SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd ) && find $SCRIPT_DIR -depth -type d -empty -delete``` to the end of the script. When I originally downloaded my music, if the artist/album names had special characters they were replaced with ```_```. This will prevent any duplicate, empty directories after renaming due to this.