# Bash script or function to rename mp3 files

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, tr

Want to batch rename mp3 files to following scheme
`my-artist_my-title.mp3`

E.g.:
Let's suppose that I have the `mp3` file: [of the song Underground‐Čoček, by Goran Bregović](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2AQrerfv60). But the file is named `s3  24)3ü6   Dț67  .mp3` (for exaple, because it was lost on a drive and [recovered with `testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Supposing the mp3 metadata is correct, the script should change the filename to:
`goran-bregovic_underground‐cocek.mp3`

Ideally I would prefer to have a `bash script` which I would trigger with:

```
$ rename-mp3 directory-with-subdirectories-with-mp3-files
```

Searching for similar solutions I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294347/bash-script-to-mass-rename-mp3s) function. I modified it and it works, *partially*! The regex modifications, marked with `#?` are not working.

```
  function rename-mp3() {       # input is an mp3 file: i.e. find -name 's3  24)3ü6   Dț67  .mp3' -exec bash -c 'rename-mp3 "$@"' bash {} \;
                                # extract metadata from file
  artist=`ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=artist -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1"`
  title=`ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=title -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1"`
  artist="${artist/\&/}"        #? delete all non-numeral, non-latin, and non-space characters (&, %, !, ', ä, ö, ü, ă, ț, etc.)
  title="${title/\&/}"          #? delete all non-numeral, non-latin, and non-space characters (&, %, !, ', ä, ö, ü, ă, ț, etc.)
  artist="${artist// +/\-}"     #? replace all spaces with "-", if more then one in sequence substitute only one "-"
  title="${artist// +/\-}"      #? replace all spaces with "-", if more then one in sequence substitute only one "-"
  filename="$artist_$title.mp3" # paste artist and title together
  filename="${name,,}"          # lowercase everything
  echo "$filename"              # display new filename
  cp "$1" "renamed/$name"       # copy renamed file to the renamed folder
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ayoisaiah/f2

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.  Sample inputs, sample outputs, what your current script produces.

Comment: @Nic3500: Thank you. A minimal example is not trivial since you can't post original songs online. However you can download one, change the metadata and test. Alternatively change the lines `3` and `4` of the code above and set the artist and title from the example above. If that's working it should be okay, the rest is already working and tested by me.

Comment: posting sample inputs does not consist of providing actual song files; sample inputs would consist of a couple filenames and a complete set of `ffprobe` data for each of the files; from that we should be able to determine how to parse the `ffprobe` data; obviously (?) the samples you provide should be sufficient to exercise/test each of the parameter substitutions

Comment: *`are not working`* doesn't tell us what's wrong ... the replacement does not take place? a wrong replacement takes place? an error message? something else? please update the question with additional details on what you mean by *`are not working`*

Comment: Observe that following your comment would turn `Goran Bregović` into `goran-bregovi` as last character would be considered non-latin akin to `ä`. Is that acceptable or you must drop diacritics without dropping letter itself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a similar script (but really more complicated) to sort all my audio files.

Based on your script:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -r input_filename="$1"
declare -r output_dirname="$2"

function rationalize() {
    local s="$1"
    # extglob option is necessary for pattern matching in bash expansions
    shopt -s extglob
    # delete all non-ascii characters
    s="${s//[^[:ascii:]]/}"
    # keep only all alpha, numeral and space characters
    s="${s//[^[:alnum:]|[:space:]]/}"
    # replace all spaces with "-", if more then one in sequence substitute only one "-"
    s="${s//+([[:space:]])/-}"
    shopt -u extglob
    printf "%s" "$s"
}

function get_tag() {
    local -r tag="$1"
    local -r filename="$2"
    local value=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags="$tag" -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$filename")
    value=$(rationalize "$value")
    printf "%s" "$value"
}

function copy_audiofile() {
    local -r from_filname="$1"
    local -r to_dir="$2"
    # get filename extension
    local -r ext="${from_filname##*.}"
    # get artist for file
    local artist=$(get_tag "artist" "$from_filname")
    # get title for file
    local title=$( get_tag "title" "$from_filname")
    # paste artist and title together
    local filename_to="${artist}_$title.$ext"
    # lowercase everything
    filename_to="${filename_to,,}"
    # display new from_filname
    echo "Rename '$from_filname' to '$filename_to'"
    # copy renamed file to the renamed folder
    cp "$1" "$to_dir/$filename_to"
}

copy_audiofile "$input_filename" "$output_dirname"
```